# Finding length of event.target.[name].value in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor.  To get the value we use `var x = event.target.[name].value;` property of `event`.  How do I get length or the number of characters in `x` using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `x` is a `String`, you can use [`.length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) on `x` to get the number of characters in the string.

```
var x = event.target.[name].value;
x.length
```

You can also obtain the length directly without an intermediate variable

```
event.target.[name].value.length
```